# How to Obtain This Partial Differential Equation Transformation?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Given that $z=\frac{A_b}{B(a,b)}$ and $S(z,b)=\frac{P(a,A_b,b)}{B(a,b)}$, then we have the following formula:$\frac{\partial P}{\partial b}=S\frac{\partial B}{\partial b}+B\frac{\partial S}{\partial b}+B\frac{\partial S}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial b}$. Can someone explain to me how they get that formula? I am desperate now. Thank you so much!

Comment: There's no way to find out with the information you give. The next best thing is to see if the equation follows from what is known. Try to find the derivatives on the right and multiply them by the coefficients and sum to see if you get the derivative on the left.

Answer (score 2):

$$P=B(a,b)S(z,b)$$
You will need $\frac{\partial S}{\partial b}$. But there is a snare because $z$ is also function of $b$.

In order to escape to the trap, we define $S$ as a function of two variables $z$ and $y$ , that is $S(z,y)$  :
$$S(a,b)=S\bigg(z(a,b), y(a,b)\bigg)$$

$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial b}= \frac{\partial S}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial b}+ \frac{\partial S}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial b}$$

In the present case $y$ is the particular function $y(a,b)=b$, thus $\frac{\partial y}{\partial b}=1$ and :
$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial b}= \frac{\partial S}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial b}+ \frac{\partial S}{\partial y}$$

The trap is made obvious : if we confuse $y$ with $b$ because $y(b)=b$ we will write 
$$ \color{red}{\frac{\partial S}{\partial b}}= \frac{\partial S}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial b}+  \color{red}{\frac{\partial S}{\partial b}}\quad\text{which seems absurd.}$$ 
As a consequence we don't confuse $y(b)$ with $b$.

$$P=B(a,b)S(z,b)$$
$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial b}=S \frac{\partial B}{\partial b}+B \frac{\partial S}{\partial b}$$

$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial b}=S \frac{\partial B}{\partial b}+B \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial b}+ \frac{\partial S}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y(b)}{\partial b}\right)$$

$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial b}=S \frac{\partial B}{\partial b}+B\frac{\partial S}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial b}+ B\frac{\partial S}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y(b)}{\partial b}$$

Of course these precautions are for people not fully familiar with the common way to deal with partial derivatives. Loosely one will commonly simplify the writing as :
$$\boxed{\frac{\partial P}{\partial b}=S \frac{\partial B}{\partial b}+B\frac{\partial S}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial b}+ B\frac{\partial S}{\partial b}}$$

Comment: Amazing effort to answer a terrible question

Comment: Oh yes, the terrible trap is still running !